# Geopolymer injection

Tags: foundation, engineering, soil

Does anyone have experience with foundation repair using geopolymer injection?

My foundation has a settlement issue mostly due an expansive fill soil.

I've been discussing it with a local geotechnical engineer but the current uncertainty is whether the geopolymer would be able to penetrate our fine grained & highly plastic clay soil. He suspects it would only be able to fill existing shallow shrinkage cracks. However the geopolymer injection company I'm speaking to says that the geopolymer would be injected under high pressure, creating fractures in the clay allowing it to then flow into the fractures.

Is anyone here familiar with this & able to comment on this?

Comment: I think I would go with/trust the engineer without his hands on your wallet than a company.  The engineer is local and should know local soil conditions, and what will work.  My opinion only since I do not know either.

Comment: I think you're better off  listening to the local engineer and the actual company that would do the work than to internet people who don't even know what part of the planet you live in.  Get some second opinions from other experts local to your area.

Comment: Ask the company to visit one of their clients,  whose work was done over a year ago. I  always do this.

Comment: Thanks - I generally agree with you guys, but the local engineer does not have experience with hydraulic fracturing of soils, just of hard rock materials. So he just doesn't know.

The geopolymer company is https://www.geobear.us which has also been doing this in Europe since the 80s on 200k+ jobs.

Also the pier approach estimate is ~$80-$100k, geopolymer ~$40-$50k, so to me it's worthwhile to investigate further. Having trouble finding anyone who has experience with this though.

Comment: @RohitGupta agree with you too. They've given me a client reference but my local engineer says the soil type is not similar enough to compare. In the US they're newer & only covering a smaller area so far which seems to have different soil conditions than where I live so not sure I'm going to get a local reference that I can compare with...

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237152521_Use_of_expanding_polyurethane_resin_to_remediate_expansive_soil_foundations looks legit for your case. Your "settlement" plus "expansive soil" suggest that you've got settlement due to dewatering of a clay below your foundation, but I can't really tell from your write up.